# How might I import data from MS-Excel into Sql Server using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, excel

I need to import data from Excel to Sql Server using ASP.NET. How can I do this?

Comment: Does it need to be done through ASP.net? If it's a once-off import, you could use the DTS wizard.

Comment: Through Asp.net code.I need the proper code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ADO.net OLEDB data source. You can fetch records as you normally do for MS Access.
Have a look at the example..

```
public static DataTable SelectAll()
{
    string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + @"\YourExcellfile.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";";
    OleDbConnection oleConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);

    OleDbCommand oleCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from [YourSheet1$]", oleConnection);
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(oleCommand);

    oleConnection.Open();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);

    oleConnection.Close();

    return dt;
}
```

After the import you can pick the data from the data table and perform the insert operation using ADO.net Sql operation

Comment: FYI, last I heard, the Jet drivers were still only supported on x86, with no plans for x64.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at

- [Importing an Excel Spreadsheet Using
  Typed DataSets and TableAdapters:
  Building the Database](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215526/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022708-1.aspx)
- [Import Excel Spreadsheet Data into
  SQL Server Database Table Using
  SqlBulkCopy](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/31/2976.aspx)
- [Asp.Net Excel File Import and
  Transfer to Sql Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20200809200743/http://geekswithblogs.net/thanigai/archive/2009/04/27/asp.net-excel-file-import-and-transfer-to-sql-server.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want your users to upload an Excel document, which then has to be imported into SQL server. If so, you can either try some third-party library to open `xls` file and read data on a row-by-row basis, `insert`ing it into an appropriate table or install Excel itself on a web server (not a good idea, though) and use it as an ODBC data source.

Comment: i want this to be happen through asp.net code.I need the proper code for this

Answer (score 0):

Besides using an ODBC data source, you can also to ask your user to export that Excel file to CSV and to import it manually.